# Status of keep original photos after switching from optimized icloud upload

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos

In order to save space on my iphone, I chose optimize storage to upload photos on icloud. My icloud subscription of that account is about to expire, and I am unable to renew it as currently I am not residing in the country for which I had the icloud account. I have made another icloud account of my current residing country. I have chosen to download and keep originals instead of optimize option in icloud photos upload in order to switch my icloud account to newer account. However, I am unable to track the progress that how many of the photos have been download to original resolution.

I would like to ask how can I track the progress of having the downloaded original resolution photos in my iphone? Also, how can I manually start the process of downloading he original photos?
I have around 8000 photos/videos in my iphone. When I scroll manually to each photo and then zoom into it, then it starts to download the original size of that photo. It is hard to scroll for each image as the number of images are very high.

Comment: I can't answer your actual question, but perhaps it would have been wiser to transfer your original account rather than make a new one - https://support.apple.com/HT201389

Comment: I am not completely sure, but I think if you disable iCloud photos it will ask you whether you want to download your photos first

Comment: If I disable iCloud photos, it says still have around 7000 photos/videos not downloaded yet. If I continue then the low resolution images will be removed from the iPhone.

Comment: @Tetsujin If I switch to another region then what about the original photos still uploaded on iCloud of my previous region? As currently in the iPhone, I have optimized (low resolution) images only. Will the original images at iCloud still be intact when I switch to new region? Or they will also be removed and then I the new region I will only have the option of uploading the low resolution images only...

Comment: I've never done it - but as you have two separate accounts in two separate countries, you now have no way to cross-reference between them.